# Is it possible to make the echo area next to cursor?

Tags: echo-area

The problem: I found it's tiredsome to move my eyeballs up and down from where my cursor is to the bottom echo area.

The question: is it possible to make the echo area dynamically allocated close to my cursor, like tooltips? I searched for packages but not able to find one. I don't believe it's a new idea and someone must've done it.

Comment: What if you echo several screenfulls of text?

Comment: @wvxvw, There could be a fallback mechanism. I've implemented exactly this for specific cases. I'm curious if there's a generic solution already.

Comment: It's possible if you use [a dedicated frame](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Dedicated_Minibuffer_Frame). It is from a package named [oneonone](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/oneonone.el). In the comment section, it is written that `1on1-minibuffer-frame-flag is non-nil (the default value), then the minibuffer is shown in its own frame`.

Comment: Closely related to [this question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1074/how-to-display-the-content-of-minibuffer-in-the-middle-of-the-emacs-frame/1078). That one's about minibuffer *input*, but it has a positive answer so you may be able to adapt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The echo area explicitly uses the minibuffer window, so unless that changes the answer is "no, it's not possible" (or at minimum not very practical).

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063410/is-it-possible-to-separate-minibuffer-and-echo-area-in-emacs

Comment: But if I intercepted `message` to display it in an overlay instead of the echo area?

Comment: Sure, if you only want this for `message`. There are many other functions which output to the echo area, however; I don't believe it's a trivial issue. As per the linked Q&A, have a look at the manual to get some idea of the scope.

Comment: Note in particular that there are many C functions which bypass `message` and instead directly call one of the C functions which implement messaging underneath.

Comment: It's sad. I was thinking to use an overlay + some codes to redirect the messagebuffer.

Comment: You can have a small frame that contains only a minibuffer window. The only difficulty is poping it up whenever the echo area is displaying anything.

Answer (score 5):

As @TuDo's comment indicates (and he can change it to an answer if he likes, in which case I'll remove this answer), you can at least use a standalone minibuffer frame, and you can position it where you like.

One advantage over the default setup is that you have only a single place to look, always, for output messages (echo area) and for input editing (minibuffer).

You could even cause its position to change dynamically - for example, to be close to where the current input focus is.

[**One On One Emacs**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OneOnOneEmacs) can help. Out of the box, it lets you decide where to put the minibuffer frame, but to reposition it dynamically you will need to do a little extra.

(EmacsWiki is currently down, but you can download `oneonone.el` from MELPA also.)

Comment: Presumably you mean [this page on the wiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/OneOnOneEmacs)? I'm not sure, but your link doesn't work.

Comment: @WilfredHughes: Thanks, I fixed the link.