# Minibuffer for each window

Tags: window, minibuffer, posframe

Is there a way to have a minibuffer window for each window? I don't want recursive minibuffers, just one per window so that I don't have to look to the bottom of the screen when editing a window placed near the top.

Comment: The following linked thread probably has the closest thing that can be achieved -- "*How to display the content of minibuffer in the middle of the emacs frame?*":  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1074/how-to-display-the-content-of-minibuffer-in-the-middle-of-the-emacs-frame  See also https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Dedicated_Minibuffer_Frame

Comment: Well, you do get by default one minibuffer per frame, so instead of figuring out how to do what you want, you could just start opening more windows in their own frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Emacs 26 and later you can use [emacs-maple-minibuffer](https://github.com/honmaple/emacs-maple-minibuffer) or [ivy-posframe](https://github.com/tumashu/ivy-posframe) if your are using [ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/blob/master/ivy.el).

Those packages let you configure to popup a minibuffer frame at any position, including the current window top/bottom. The docs of those packages describe how to set them up.

Comment: Just for completeness of information, can you mention if they need specific Emacs versions, e.g. only 26 and above or so?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using command-line emacs rather than the gui version you could consider using [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux) panes rather than emacs windows. If you run emacs as a server you can then have an emacsclient running in as many tmux panes as you like. Each will have its own minibuffer display at the bottom.